# Round to 5 and 9 php

Tags: php

I'm looking for a formula to round a value to nearest 5 or 9 if the val is less than 5 make 5 if is bigger than 5 make 9.

Example:

```
$RoundToFive = ceil('232' / 5) * 5;
echo floor($RoundToFive  * 2 ) / 2; //Result is 235 Is good

$RoundToNine = ceil('236' / 5) * 5;
echo floor($RoundToNine  * 2 ) / 2; //Result is 240 but i need 239
```

Is there a way to extract always the last 2 digits and convert to 5 or nine ?

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Tried with PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN, etc, but no luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
function funnyRound($number){
    $rounded = ceil($number / 5) * 5;
    return $rounded%10?$rounded:$rounded-1;
}
```

Comment: it's quite crude admittedly but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
<?php
function roundToDigits($num, $suffix, $type = 'floor') {
    $pow = pow(10, floor(log($suffix, 10) + 1));
    return $type(($num - $suffix) / $pow) * $pow + $suffix; 
};
$RoundToNine = ceil('236' / 5) * 5;
echo roundToDigits($RoundToNine,5);
echo roundToDigits($RoundToNine,9);
```

You can use any number as $suffix to round to it.

Comment: Hey @Jomon, yes, it works for 236, but not for 232 it makes 229 instead 235 :).

Comment: use $suffix as 5.   echo roundToDigits($RoundToNine,5);

Answer (score 0):

other way, working with strings... :

```
<?php

function round59($NUMB){

    //cast the value to be Int
    $NUMB = intval($NUMB);

    //Get last number
    $last_number = intval(substr($NUMB, -1)); 

    $ROUND_NUMBER = 5;
    if($last_number<=5)
        $ROUND_NUMBER = 5;
    else
        $ROUND_NUMBER = 9;

    //Remove Last Character
    $NUMB = substr($NUMB, 0, -1);

    // now concat the results 
    return intval($NUMB."".$ROUND_NUMBER) ; 
} 

echo round59(232);
echo round59(236);
?>
```